# Convergence of random increment of two bins

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

If bins A and B are initialized to 1, and then I continually increment one of them by 1 with a probability proportional to their values, would A/B ever converge?

To demonstrate

```
A=1 B=1 , select A or B with 50-50 -> A chosen
A=2 B=1 , select A or B with 66-33 -> A chosen
A=3 B=1 , etc
```

For A=1 and B=1 it seems to diverge most of the time. But if I start from larger numbers A=100 B=100 it seems that it will converge to 50-50 after many iterations. And If I start from A=100 B=200 it would converge to 33-66 etc. So the initial value is important.

What is the mathematical explanation for this behavior? Maybe the initial value  is a function of the increment (1 in this case) in some way to be able to ensure convergence.

Comment: This process is called *Pólya's urn*. You can find many informations about the convergence on the web.

Comment: Indeed, wiki calls it the 'rich gets richer' scheme which is what happens here too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be formulated as a special random walk.

Let $X_n$ ($n\ge 1)$ be a set of Bernoulli variables, taking values on $\{1,-1\}$, and let $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_n$ be our random walk. Making the event $X_n=1$ correspond to incrementing $A_n$, we have:

$$ (A_n-A_0)-(B_n-B_0) = Y_n$$
$$ (A_n-A_0)+(B_n-B_0) = n$$

Hence $A_n = A_0 + (Y_n+n)/2$ and $A_n + B_n = n+A_0+B_0$

Then

$$p_n= P(X_n=1) = \frac{A_{n-1}}{A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{Y_{n-1}+n-1+2A_0}{n-1+A_0+B_0}$$

Letting $\mu_n=E(X_n)$, conditioning on the past, and applying the tower expectation, we get (I spare the details) :

$$ \mu_n= \frac{\alpha +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mu_i}{\beta +n} $$

where $\alpha=A_0-B_0$ and $\beta = A_0+B_0-1$. This has the constant solution: $\mu_n = \frac{\alpha}{\beta+1}=\frac{A_0-B_0}{A_0+B_0}$. Therefore

$$E(Y_n)=n \frac{A_0-B_0}{A_0+B_0}$$

and hence $A_n$ grows (in average) as $A_0 + n (\frac{A_0-B_0}{A_0+B_0}+\frac{1}{2})$

What remains is to compute the variance of $Y_n$, which requires to compute the correlations $E(X_n X_m)$. As a starting point, note that $\sigma_X^2=4 A_0 B_0 /(A_0+B_0)^2$. If $X_n$ were indepdent, $\sigma_Y^2= n \sigma_X^2$ . Because they have positive correlation, one would expect the variance to be larger - but not larger than $n^2 \sigma_X^2$.

Update: A straightforward but tedious computation [*] gives me: $$r=E(X_n X_m) = \frac{s+d^2}{  s(s+1)} \hskip{1cm} n\ne m, \;s=A_0+B_0, \; d=A_0-B_0$$

Then $E(Y_n^2)=n+n(n-1) r$ ; and, because  $E(Y_n)=n d/s$ then

$$ {\rm{Var}}(Y_n)=n\frac{s^2-d^2}{s(s+1)}\left(\frac{n}{s} +1\right) \approx n^2 \frac{s^2-d^2}{s^2(s+1)}$$

Going back to $A_n$, we see that its mean grows as

$$\overline{A_n} \approx n \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{d}{s}\right)$$

and the variance as

$$ {\rm Var}(A_n) \approx n^2 \frac{s^2-d^2}{4 s^2(s+1)}$$

In particular,  $A_0=B_0=1$ ($d=0$, $s=2$) we have

$$\overline{A_n} =1+\frac{n}{2} \hskip{1cm} {\rm Var}(A_n) \approx n^2 \frac{1}{12}$$

If instead $A_0=B_0=100$

$$\overline{A_n} =100+\frac{n}{2} \hskip{1cm} {\rm Var}(A_n) \approx n^2 \frac{1}{804}$$

That is, the behaviour is basically the same in the mean, but the variance is smaller.

[*] I've checked my results against simulations, they seem to agree. BTW, I confess I was surprised to find that both the mean and the correlation of $X_n$ are constants, perhaps I'm missing some basic insight and some simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't understood all of it but the first step where you converted it to Bernoulli trials is brilliant. I was basically stuck on a recurrence relation for $E(A_n) = A_{n-1} + \frac{A_{n-1}}{A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}}$

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeing is called the [Law of large numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

The greater the number of random choices you make the more closely the numbers will converge to their probabilities.

As this is a [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and therefore has a finite first moment (mean) then it satisfies the criteria for strong convergence.

So for a probability of selecting $A$ of $p_a$ and an initial value of $A_0$ and $B_0$, after $n$ trials you will [almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) converge to:

$$A_n=np_a+A_0$$
$$B_n=n(1-p_a)+B_0$$

And, because we know the structure of [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) very well we can go further and state that they will have a mean of $np_a+A_0$ and $n(1-p_a)+B_0$ respectively with a variance of $np_a(1-p_a)$.

Now, for sufficiently large $n$, $A_0$ and $B_0$ are insignificant. So the initial values are irrelevant. How irrelevant you can quantify from the variance.

Comment: The problem here is that p_a is not a constant. It depends on the values of A and B at that iteration. If A_0 and B_0 are small an increment of 1 can cause divergence.

Comment: Ah, I see - let me think about that.